# This excel file has number value which is in text format i have tried all steps to convert it into number but its not happening?

Tags: excel

[image]Excel file has number value which in text value format
how to convert it back into number value format so please check.

Comment: Are there spaces either side of the decimal point? Might be the font, but looks like there's too much space there.

Comment: yes that was the issue thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces from the texts and convert it into a number:

```
VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(N2;" ";""))
```

In the case `.` is not the decimal seperator on you system, take an extra step to replace that as well (either from `,` to `.` or vice versa):

```
VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(N2,".",",")," ",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the . the decimal separator on your system?

If not then you have to replace each one with the correct separator.

FIND/REPLACE will make this easy.

Note: Excel shows these are all recognized as text since they are to the left of the cell, numbers are automatically to the right. Unless you change the formatting.